# how to use a custom Function in Oracle Statement on each value of one column using Scala

Tags: oracle, scala

I have a Scala Function. I need to read records that their last two characters of **ID** column are equal to the result of `func`. So, I must use `func` in Oracle query which is in following:

```
 def func(id:String): Int = {
   val two_char = id.takeRight(2).toInt
   val group_id = two_char % 4
   return group_id
  }

val query = """ SELECT * FROM table where """+func("ID") + """==="""+group_id
```

When Scala run the query, I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ID"
```

`func` pass name of column not its values. Would you please guide me how to use the function in **Oracle Query** to operate on each value of the column?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: The problem is about your `func` logic. `"ID".takeRight(2).toInt` throws an exception since "ID" is not a number so it cannot convert it to Int. What is the aim of func?? Please give us more details about it.

Comment: Dear @gianluca aguzzi, thank you for your feedback. I update my question; please see it.

Comment: @M_Gh, do you have a way to print the `scala` query before executing it ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez, I cannot print the query. Since, I receive the error exactly in running query.

Comment: I think the java engine is interpreting ID as a string without being passed to the function itself. I don't know Scala, but should not appear as `+func` so not as a literal ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez,I don't think so. I think I must write ```func``` with pl/sql to use in Oracle query. I mean write a new store procedure.

Comment: @M_Gh , I was just guessing, as I don't know Scala. you could use a function in Oracle and then use it in the query. That could be a solution.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez, yeah thank you.